# Get rid of the trailing string with regex [PHP]

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my `regex`.

Could someone give me some guidance?

Please note that it's not always going to be `<a>` tag or `<img>` tag this is why i've not gone for the route with `DOM()`

HTML:

```
<a href="http://domain.co.uk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-4181" src="http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-300x225.jpg" alt="dscn8900" width="300" height="225" srcset="http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-300x225.jpg 300w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-768x576.jpg 768w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-1024x768.jpg 1024w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-195x146.jpg 195w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-50x38.jpg 50w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-93x70.jpg 93w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></a>
```

PREG_MATCH_ALL:

```
preg_match_all('/(((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\:[0-9]+)?(\/\S*)?(\W)/', $HTMLSourceCode, $results, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

RESULT

```
print_r($results[0][0]);
// http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900.jpg">
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900.jpg
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use `DOM` instead.

Comment: @anubhava - You got example of this? - I'm using Regex as it's a string, so thought it'd be easier

Comment: Reason for DownVote?

Comment: Replace `\S*` with `[^"]*`, remove the `(\W)`. For a one-off script regexp are fine, for a project lasting longer use anubhava's solution.

Comment: @TomRegner OMG thank you! I've been trying to find out this solution for ages. I can never get the hang of `regex`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `DOM` example of doing this job:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<a href="http://domain.co.uk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900.jpg">
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-4181" src="http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-300x225.jpg" alt="dscn8900" width="300" height="225" srcset="http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-300x225.jpg 300w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-768x576.jpg 768w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-1024x768.jpg 1024w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-195x146.jpg 195w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-50x38.jpg 50w, http://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900-93x70.jpg 93w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></a>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//a/@href');

echo $nodeList->item(0)->value . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
http://domain.co.uk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DSCN8900.jpg
```

Comment: So i would have to do each tag seperate like - `$nodeList = $xpath->query('//a/@href');` and `$nodeList = $xpath->query('//img/@href');` ?

Comment: Yes for `a->href` but ff you want to capture `image->src` then use `$nodeList = $xpath->query('//img/@src);`